# Is it safe to use jQuery instead of HTML to upload files in a form?

Tags: jquery, file, upload

hi 
I know pretty much about HTML-PHP form building.
But I am new to jQuery.

My Question is :
Is it safe to use jQuery instead of HTML to upload files in a form?

I mean the security of the form.

Is it safe to use something like http://www.uploadify.com instead of HTML-PHP to upload images like avatars in a public website?

What precautions should I make?

Comment: In terms of security, it's about the same. You'd be using PHP on the back-end either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue using jQuery to help with uploads on your site. If you are looking at something like Uploadify, you should note this information on their [About page](http://www.uploadify.com/about/):

> Uploadify is a jQuery plugin that
>   integrates a fully-customizable
>   multiple file upload utility on your
>   website. **It uses a mixture of
>   Javascript, ActionScript, and any
>   server-side language to dynamically
>   create an instance over any DOM
>   element on a page.** [emphasis mine]

It is impossible to use pure JavaScript to upload a file due to security concerns, so, ultimately, you will be hitting server-side code at some point. And, as always, you should always perform security checks and validations server-side to ensure that everything is safe.

Comment: @John - No problem. If this does help you out, please feel free to accept the answer (click the green checkmark) so that people who have this question in the future can find a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't get confused, you apply the same techniques in any case (the Browser transmitting a form/file) The only difference is if you do it "normal" or via jQuery using a asynchronous Browser Call, the safety Options you have are exactly the same, only the methods vary.